# MSBuild - Transforming web.config

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I have set up a CI build on TFS2010 using the default workflow as defined in CIBuildWithCopyDirectoryTemplate.xaml.

It appears to be transforming web.config but I can't for the life of me figure where this has been defined. There is an `AfterBuild` task in my csproj file but I don't think MSBuild uses this?

After poring through the XAML as both text file and in its workflow form has left me completely stumped and I don't yet have the time to read the Hashimi book I bought last week. I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

AfterBuild generally is called after packaging is done for the project. The web.config transform will happen for your project prior to this during its packaging phase.

Comment: So MSBuild *does* use the projects's `.csproj` file?

Comment: Absolutely. Visual Studio C# project files are MSBuild files, and while projects invoked via command-line MSBuild and TFS can have a slightly different environment context versus an in-GUI Visual Studio build they are one and the same.

Answer (score 1):

`.csproj` files are MSBuild files. Anything you customize in the `.csproj` will be picked up by MSBuild provided the conditions are met.

You can increase [MSBuild logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470) verbosity to analyze the build internals.

Answer (score 1):

Transformation of web.config is done by VS's web publishing tasks, specifically Package target. Your .csproj should have an import of Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets in it that would define TransformXml task and few targets like [Pre|Post]TransformWebConfig that msbuild would call.